# Plone/Solgema.fullcalendar- In a folder with Solgema.fullcalendar as the view, how can I use a custom add/edit form for a content type?

Tags: plone, dexterity

I have a dexterity content type that adds to its behaviors plone.app.event.dx.behaviors.IEventBasic and I have a folder where solgema.fullcalendar is the display view and its event type under calendar settings is 'my.product.myeventtype'.  I have custom add and edit forms for the dexterity content type.

When the folder's display is the default, the custom add/edit forms appear and function as they should.  However, when the display view is fullcalendar and I try to add the content through the calendar, a form for the content type does show up, but its not the custom forms.  I tried a print statement in a updateWidgets function and the print statement did not appear in the console.

For now I'm testing an edit form:

```
from plone.dexterity.browser import add, edit

class Edit(edit.DefaultEditForm):
    def updateWidgets(self):
        super(updateWidgets, self).updateWidgets()
        print "Test"
```

In config.zcml:

```
<browser:page
    for=".my_event_type.IMyEventType"
    name="edit"
    class=".my_event_type.EditForm"
    permission="cmf.ModifyPortalContent"
/>
```

*The dexterity type's module is "my_event_type.py", while in its xml file, it is "my.product.myeventtype."

source: http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/advanced/custom-add-and-edit-forms.html

I've also tried using dexterity.EditForm from plone.directives and grok.

```
from five import grok
from plone.directives import dexterity

class EditForm(dexterity.EditForm):

    grok.context(IMyEventType)

    def updateWidgets(self):
        """ """
        dexterity.EditForm.updateWidgets(self)
        print "test"
```

source: http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/content/dexterity.html

Since these attempts do not appear to work, how can I use my own custom form for adding an "event"?

The reason I'd like to use custom add and edit forms is that I need to be able to use updateWidgets so I can set the default value of a choice box equal to the current logged in user.  Also, I'd like to be able to use my own submit handler as opposed to the default one, but I am relying on event subscribers for now.